# DirectX 11 enum D3D11_USAGE and D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY warning

Tags: c++, enums, directx-11

When using DirectX 11 and MSVS2019 I get the following warnings when using the enums 'D3D11_USAGE' and 'D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY:

> Warning   C26812  The enum type 'D3D11_USAGE' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum
>   class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).
>
> Warning   C26812  The enum type 'D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY' is unscoped.
>   Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).

What can I do to resolve those warnings? The code works fine with the warnings, but I rather have them gone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C26812 is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ Code Analysis (`/analyze` ) [C++ Core Guidelines checkers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-core-guidelines-checker-in-visual-studio-2017/) rules.

Generally the warnings in the Windows 10 SDK system headers are automatically suppressed. 
 The mostly likely problem is that you are using the legacy DirectX SDK, as those headers will not be automatically suppressed.

First thing to consider is removing all use of the legacy DirectX SDK. The Windows 10 SDK that comes with Visual Studio 2019 already contains all the Direct3D headers you need. If you are using XNAMath, you can use [DirectXMath](https://walbourn.github.io/introducing-directxmath/) instead. If you are using the legacy D3DX11 library, move to one of the [open source alternatives](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/). If you are using XAudio 2.7, use the [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/xaudio2redist) instead. If you are using the D3DX library to compile your HLSL shaders, use [D3DCompile](https://walbourn.github.io/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/) directly instead. If you are using XInput 1.3, look at using a [built-in XInput](https://walbourn.github.io/xinput-and-windows-8/) version instead.

If removing the legacy DirectX SDK is not a viable option, then adjust your include/lib paths so that you get the Windows 10 SDK headers whenever possible instead. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) for details, but in short edit *VC++ Directories* so that the `DXSDK_DIR` include/lib paths are *LAST* instead of *FIRST* in the search order.

You can also ignore the warning by suppressing it with `#pragma warning(disable : 26812)` and/or the command-line option `/wd26812`. The C++ Core Guidelines checkers are a little pedantic, and in some cases are really just [advice](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).

The Visual C++ team has removed a lot of the checkers from the **Microsoft Native Recommended Rules** but still has 26812 listed. You can create a custom ruleset, or disable Code Analysis on Build as well. Personally, I just suppress this one in my projects as I have good reasons to NOT use a `class enum`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very helpfull, I will look into it further.